# Add a page to the admin where you can upload and download a file

Tags: admin, magento2.4.5

What I would like to do is add a field to an admin page where a file can be downloaded and uploaded. A client would like to upload a csv file that is used by a module developt by an agency that was developing the site before us.

What I have is that I have been able to add a page to the backend, a download and an upload field.

[image]

```xml
<!-- app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="modulename" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
            <tab>catalog</tab>
            <label>Module Name</label>

            <group id="general" translate="label" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>

                <field id="download" translate="label" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Download" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1">
                    <label>Download</label>
                </field>
                <field id="upload_plates_file" translate="label" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Upload" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1">
                    <label>Upload</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

And the two files; `Upload.php` and `Download.php`.

```php
// app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/Upload.php
class Upload extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    [...__construtor()...]

    protected function _construct(): void
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setType('file');
    }

    public function getElementHtml(): string
    {
        return parent::getElementHtml();
    }
}
```

```php
// app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/Download.php 
class Download extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    [...__constructor()...]

    public function getElementHtml(): string
    {
        $buttonBlock = $this->getForm()->getParent()->getLayout()->createBlock(Button::class);
        $params = ['website' => $buttonBlock->getRequest()->getParam('website')];
        $url = $this->backendUrl->getUrl("*/*/exportPlatesCsv", $params);
        $data = [
            'label' => __('Export CSV'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('" .
                $url .
                "somewhere/somefile.csv' )",
            'class' => '',
        ];
        return $buttonBlock->setData($data)->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Now I understand that I need controllers for the actual upload and download action, and I have a `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Download.php` and a `app/code/Elgentos/DownUploadPlatesCSV/Model/Config/Backend/Upload.php`. And I have some scafolding inside there, but it does nothing and I wouldn't know where to begin to fix it.

I know this perhaps isn't a lot to go by and debugging something on a system you don't have access to is next to impossible but a nudge in the right direction or an article that covers this use case, which I have not been able to find, would be wonderful! (BTW using magento 2.4.5-p1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help form a colleague we figured it out. It was not as easy as I had expected it would be, but that's magento for you. Documentation is also lacking but that's magento for you...

What I had was good but I indeed needed a controller and a model. First the model:

```php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend;

use Laminas\Stdlib\ParametersInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http\Proxy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class PlatesCsv extends Value
{
    public const DIRECTORY_NAME = 'directoryname';
    public const FILE_NAME = 'filename.csv';


    public function __construct(
        private readonly Proxy $request,
        private readonly WriteFactory $writeFactory,
        private readonly Filesystem $filesystem,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList,
            $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @throws ValidatorException
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function afterSave(): static
    {
        if(!$this->request->getFiles('groups')) {
            return parent::afterSave();
        }

        /** @var ParametersInterface|mixed $uploadedPlatesFile */
        $uploadedPlatesFile = $this->request->getFiles('groups')['general']['fields']['upload_plates_file']['value'];

        $rootDir = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
        $uploadDir = $this->writeFactory->create($rootDir->getAbsolutePath(self::DIRECTORY_NAME));
        $realpath = $uploadDir->getDriver()->getRealPathSafety($uploadDir->getAbsolutePath(self::FILE_NAME));
        $uploadDir->getDriver()->copy(
            $uploadedPlatesFile['tmp_name'],
            $realpath
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the controller, the `execute()` function was a lot of trail and error:

```php
// app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/ControllerName.php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend\ModelName;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig;
use Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\ConfigSectionChecker;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ControllerName extends AbstractConfig
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Structure $configStructure,
        ConfigSectionChecker $sectionChecker,
        private readonly FileFactory $fileFactory,
        private readonly LoggerInterface $logger,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $configStructure, $sectionChecker);
    }

    public function execute(): ?ResponseInterface
    {
        try {
            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                ModelName::PLATES_FILE_NAME,
                [
                    'type'  => 'filename',
                    'value' => ModelName::DIRECTORY_NAME . '/' . ModelName::FILE_NAME,
                ],
                DirectoryList::ROOT
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The file will now be saved at the following location, relative to the Magento root dir: `magento_root/directory_name/filename.csv`.

Comment: that sound great. Please mark your answer as “accepted” answer, that indicates your issue was resolved by the solution in your answer.